SpaProxy not launching on local docker environment. npm start not working inside container

Launching the SPA proxy...
Error on Docker logs:
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
Failed to launch the SPA development server 'npm run start'.
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (2): An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/local/bin/npm' with working directory '/app/bin/Debug/net6.0/C:\repos\DMMRuntime\Core\DmmService\ClientApp'. No such file or directory
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ForkAndExecProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo, String resolvedFilename, String[] argv, String[] envp, String cwd, Boolean setCredentials, UInt32 userId, UInt32 groupId, UInt32[] groups, Int32& stdinFd, Int32& stdoutFd, Int32& stderrFd, Boolean usesTerminal, Boolean throwOnNoExec)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartCore(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager.LaunchDevelopmentProxy()
app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = Path.Join(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "ClientApp");
    //spa.Options.SourcePath = _spaRoot;
    
});

Docker file that installs node
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_lts.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs

csproj settings for SpaProxy
<SpaRoot>ClientApp\</SpaRoot>
<ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
<DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
<DefaultItemExcludes>$(DefaultItemExcludes);$(SpaRoot)node_modules\**</DefaultItemExcludes>
<SpaProxyServerUrl>http://localhost:44405</SpaProxyServerUrl>
<SpaProxyLaunchCommand>npm run start</SpaProxyLaunchCommand>

vite.config.js
export default defineConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: "process/browser",
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib",
            util: 'util'
        }
    },
    server: {
        proxy: {
            //private routing
        },
        host: true,
        port: 44405
    },
    build: {
        outDir: 'build',
        emptyOutDir: true
    },
    plugins: [
        plugin()
    ]
})

I tried to change UseSpa configurations. I tried to change node installation to multistaged one. I tried to change vite.config.js. But no luck until now.

There is an open issue on github for this problem https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/41093
